# Why is showing a UIAlertView in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: causing an error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

On the first run of my application I show an alert view to the user to choose iCloud or local document storage. Showing the alert view causes the following error:

> Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of
>   application launch wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Why is this happening? How do you show an alert view on start-up without getting this error?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Check the user preferences for document storage options
    if (![UserPreferencesHelper userDocumentStoragePreferencesHaveBeenCreated])
    {
        // User preferences have not been set, prompt the user to choose either iCloud or Local data storage
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Use iCloud?" 
                                                        message:@"Would you like to store data in iCloud?" 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"No", @"Yes", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

** UPDATE **

I should mention that I'm using iOS 5 with storyboards.  The root view controller is set in the storyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing `[alert show]` with:

```
[alert performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

This delays the alert for a single pass through the runloop, presumably allowing your app's controllers and storyboards to complete their setup before the alert is presented.

Comment: Darren, thank you! That worked perfectly =). I was banging my head on the wall for a while on this one...

Answer (score 2):

Like it says, you need a root controller for your app. Alerts appear above the normal controller-managed views so you need a controller-managed view for it to appear above.

Comment: hm, I've set my rootview controller in the storyboard.  So I guess what you are saying is at this point, when applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called, the rootview controller has not been created. Correct?

Comment: Right, sounds like somehow the wiring got messed up somewhere. Not an answer, but maybe an indication of where to look? (Sorry, I don't know anything about storyboards.)

Answer (score 0):

Before your app gets to the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: it needs to have a rootViewController set.  You can set this property for a ViewController named viewController with:

```
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Note that setting a controller as the rootViewController automatically adds the view.  So, you don't need to add the view again with:

```
[self setViewController:];
```

Comment: AtkinsonCM, I believe they changed this around a bit with the use of storyboards in iOS5.  I should have mentioned that in my original post.  I'll update it...