# Display Contents of PDF opened in iOS App (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I have an app that is configured so that PDFs in other applications such as mail, I can hold down on the PDF and it will have the open to "open in" my app; I have that working and my app opens, but now I want to display that document in my app, how do I do that? I am pretty sure that I have to use AppDelegate, but I just started using Swift and am completely lost and cannot find a tutorial that helps with this task, so any help would be appreciated.

AppDelegate.swift

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
let UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey: String = ""

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey.isEmpty {
        print("String is empty.")
    }
    else{

    let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "PDF UPLOAD"
    alertView.message = "??"
    alertView.delegate = self
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertView.show()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, you can handle setting up your UI to display the PDF. You can use UIWebView to render the document.

[iPhone : can we open pdf file using UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview)

EDIT:

[This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1) explains the launch options you can listen for in AppDelegate. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey) will contain the URL pointing to your file.

Comment: But how do I actually access that PDF when it is opened in my app?

Comment: I found this link that might help:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1

Comment: So I added some of my AppDelegate.swift code above, I am trying to open the app with a PDF, and if it does I assume with the code I wrote it would display an alertview, I did this because I realized if I close the app on my iPhone then the connection is gone with the console on xcode. Either way, I was unable to get the alertview to display which assumes I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040896/why-is-showing-a-uialertview-in-applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions-causi) if you NEED to display an alert here.

I would recommend instantiating a view controller that can handle this interaction for you.

Comment: I don't need an alert I am just using it to test my method

Comment: Try instantiating a view controller, setting a URL property, and then set that view controller as the rootViewController. 

Then, handle your interactions from your PDFUploadViewController, and segue back into your normal application flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83909/discussion-between-john-smith-and-u-s-coding-team-benchwarmer).